# Network, route, topology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology, route, geometric-network

I have two feature classes. One is a point feature class, the other is a line feature class. The point features all intersect the line feature. I want to route the line feature (have line symbology point to) to point features whose attributes are of lesser value. I havent been able to find an automated option setting up a network, using topology, or using the route tool. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

[image: arc map image]

[image: What I'm trying to make happen]

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you're asking here, it seems you want to find the points that have a lesser value than the lines, is this correct? Have you tried buffer and spatial join? Near? Do you have an advanced license?

Comment: The lines don't have values, but I want them to route to the points of lesser value. I have standard with some extensions. I tried spatial joining but that doesn't segment the lines at the points. If the point features were the nodes of the line feature, I might could get it from there.

Comment: The values are an attribute field in the points layer, to clarify.

Comment: Points on lines are called 'junctions', they can participate in a network and routes do not need to be broken where junctions exist. Lesser is a comparative term, less than what? If the lines don't have values how can you say a point is lesser, greater or equal?

Comment: Lesser as in closer to zero. All values are positive. I want the line layer to point toward the points in the point layer that have values closer to zero.

Comment: I'm going to try to create a feature class with junctions and see if that takes me any where. I will update tomorrow.

Comment: I would suggest you spatial join the points to the lines (nearest) to get the FID/OID of the closest line, perform a summary statistic on the joined points with a case of NEAR_FID and a statistic of MIN of the value field to get the minimum value for each line, this will give you the smallest value of point for a given line but how you implement this is a little confusing. Can you draw a picture of what you're expecting?

Comment: I'll try that. I'll take some more screen shots and make some notes on it that will explain it better

Comment: I uploaded a picture of what i'm trying to make the directional arrows on the lines do.  I want to do this without digitizing them or having to go through and flip all the lines that are backward. I got a little closer today. I don't know if it's possible to do this.